# Sublime Text 2 snippet all-caps when typing in fields

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext-snippet

I want to simplify the typing of this:

`export const RECEIVE_POSTS = 'RECEIVE_POSTS'`

I then came up with this snippet:

```
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[
export const ${1/(.+)/\U$1/g} = '${1/(.+)/\U$1/g}'
${1}
]]></content>
  <tabTrigger>con</tabTrigger>
  <scope>source.js</scope>
  <description>ES6 Module Export Variable</description>
</snippet>
```

However, the downside is that I need to delete the originally typed input.

**Is is possible that the letters be automatically transformed into all-caps when first typing in the field${1}?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a perfect solution, but this is an improved snippet:

```
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[
export const ${1/(.+)/\U$1/g} = '$1'
]]></content>
  <tabTrigger>con</tabTrigger>
  <scope>source.js</scope>
  <description>ES6 Module Export Variable</description>
</snippet>
```

This will convert the part before the `=` to uppercase. The part after that will be lowercase, but Sublime Text immediately offers to complete it to the uppercase variant. Tested in Sublime Text 3.