# Sublime Text 3 Get and Set Snippet Java

Tags: java, sublimetext-snippet

I'm trying to create a snippets to automatically generate getters and setters in java

The problem is that i don't know how to split the string taken from **$TM_SELECTED_TEXT**

The code needs to be inserted below the constructor

After I select the text it's look like this **String name**

Here's the code, I miss split string and the insert of the code under constructor because I have no idea how to do it

```
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[
    public void set$TM_SELECTED_TEXT($TM_SELECTED_TEXT $TM_SELECTED_TEXT) {
      this.$TM_SELECTED_TEXT = $TM_SELECTED_TEXT;
    }

    public $TM_SELECTED_TEXT get$TM_SELECTED_TEXT {
      return this.$TM_SELECTED_TEXT;
    }
  ]]></content>
  <tabTrigger>getter_setter</tabTrigger>
  <scope>source.java</scope>
</snippet>
```

I also would like to know how to change the first letter of the varname to uppercase just to make it look **getName** and **setName** instead of **setname** and **getname***

Answer (score 2):

You can split string in snippet using *[regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681945/sublime-text-2-snippet-all-caps-when-typing-in-fields)*. But I advice to create plugin instad of snippet. You can use python *split()* function in sublime plugin and *capitalize()* to change the first letter of the varname to uppercase.

To access selection in plugin use this construction:

```
self.view.sel()[0]
```

to insert getter or setter code use:

```
self.view.replace(edit, region, content)
```

or:

```
self.view.insert(edit, position, content)
```

This code works for me:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class javamagicCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        snippet_code = ''' public void set$TM_SELECTED_PART1($TM_SELECTED_PART1 $TM_SELECTED_PART2) {
      this.$TM_SELECTED_PART1 = $TM_SELECTED_PART1;
    }'''
        new_content = ''

        for selection in self.view.sel():
            selection_content = self.view.substr(selection)
            if selection_content.find('.') > 0:
                parts = selection_content.split('.')
                new_content = snippet_code.replace('$TM_SELECTED_PART1', parts[0])
                new_content = new_content.replace('$TM_SELECTED_PART2', parts[1])
                self.view.insert(edit, selection.begin(), new_content)
            else:
                sublime.status_message('wrong selection') # statusline message
                # sublime.message_dialog('wrong selection') # popup message

        for selection in self.view.sel():
            self.view.erase(edit, selection)

        #print('done') # debug output to console
```